# android maps v2 polygon transparency

Tags: android, transparency, polygons, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps v2 API for android and I don't manage to control the transparency of the fillColor. 
I would like to be able to see the map under a filled polygon.
Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, let me describe how standard 4 bytes color is encoded:

Standard pixel color consists of 4 bytes:

- A (alpha channel) - 0-255 (0 - fully transparent, 255 - fully opaque)
- R (red color channel) - 0-255
- G (green color channel) - 0-255
- B (blue color channel) - 0-255

Each channel represents the saturation of particular color part. So if we need to create fully opaque red color, we need to specify following channel values:

- 255,255,0,0

If we want to make it half-transparent, we need to divide alpha channel value by 2 (255/2 = 127):

- 127,255,0,0

So let's go back to the android. In Android in most cases you can specify color by specifying it's hex value:

`polygon.setFillColor(0xFF00FF00); //not transparent green color`

In hex every channel can be specified by 2 hex digits:

- A(FF)
- R(00)
- G(FF)
- B(00)

If you want to make this color half-transparent, you need to divide `FF` by 2:

```
0xFF/2 = 0x7F //the same as 255/2 = 127
```

`polygon.setFillColor(0x7F00FF00); //half-transparent green color`

So basically what you need to do - is to play with alpha channel value in order to get transparency you are looking for

Comment: Great answer. I have a couple of additional comments. I came here because I was looking for PolygonOptions to have an alpha() method like MarkerOptions. It doesn't so you have to shift your thinking a bit when you're using the two. (Markers don't have a color setting method.) Also, android.graphics.Color has methods for building a color with an alpha channel, specifically Color.argb().

Answer (score 4):

```
 cir=map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(10.938341, 76.9548734))
.radius(150)
.strokeColor(Color.rgb(0, 50, 100))
.strokeWidth(5)
.fillColor(Color.argb(20, 50, 0, 255)) 
.zIndex(55));

 cir.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what worked for Me is :

```
  polygon = mGoogleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().
        addAll(points)
            .fillColor(0x33FF0000)
             .strokeColor(Color.RED)
               .strokeWidth(3))
```