# Highlight all the worlds in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app in which the user can select points on a Google Maps and create areas based on point-radius and display them on the map with a semi-transparent circle of a specific color. The user is also able to insert "all world" areas. I need to display this "all-world" area on the map, is it possible to add a semi-transparent polygon that cover all the map? Or, is there a better solution to highlight all the map?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of [Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polygons) under the Shapes in Google Maps Android API to cover the map.

Polygon objects are similar to Polyline objects in that they consist of a series of coordinates in an ordered sequence. However, instead of being open-ended, polygons are designed to define regions within a closed loop with the interior filled in.

To create Polygon, first create a [`PolygonOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolygonOptions) object and add some points to it. These points will form the outline of the polygon. You then add the polygon to the map by calling [`GoogleMap.addPolygon(PolygonOptions)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#addPolygon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions)) which will return a Polygon object.

To alter the shape of this polygon, just call the `Polygon.setPoints()` and provide a new list of points for the outline of the polygon.

Now, for customizing the appearance of the polygon, just check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#customizing_appearances). And for the semi-transparent polygon that you want, you can check these [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/semi-transparent-color-for-fillcolor-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326482/android-maps-v2-polygon-transparency) on how to achieve that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I'm able to create a polygon, but, is it possible to cover the entire map with it? What coordinates should I specify? I can't find them under the offical documentation.